# Why is the composition of Hartshorne-smooth morphisms H-smooth? - a question on irreducible components

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I got stuck at Section III, Proposition 10. 1(c) of Hartshorne "Algebraic Geometry," which states that the composition of two smooth morphisms is again smooth.

Here, smoooth means the following.

> The morphism $f: X\to Y$ between schemes of finite type over a field $k$ are called smooth of relative dimension $n$ if
>
> 1. $f$ is flat,
> 2. for every irreducible component $X'$ of $X$, and $Y'$ of $Y$ with $f(X')\subseteq Y'$, $\mathrm{dim} X'- \mathrm{dim} Y'=n$, and
> 3. for every $x\in X$, $\mathrm{dim}_{k(x)}(\Omega_{X/Y}\otimes k(x))=n$.

I am thinking that condition 2 is unusual compared to other textbooks, and this makes things difficult for me.

Especially, I cannot understand the following part of the proof of Proposition 10.1(c). Let $f:X\to Y$, and $g:Y\to Z$ be smooth of dimension $m$, and $n$. Then, the author states that the condition 2 of the smoothness for $g\circ f$ easily follows because, if $X'$, $Y'$, and $Z'$ are irreducible components of $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ with $f(X')\subseteq Y'$, and $g(Y')\subseteq Z'$, then $\mathrm{dim} X'-\mathrm{dim} Z' = m+n$. I was wondering if you could answer why you could take such $Z'$ for arbitrary $X'$, and $Z'$ with $g(f(X'))\subseteq Z'$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems that the condition of being irreducible appears in many parts of Section III. 10 due to this condition 2.

Comment: Perhaps you are interested to take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3135255/hartshornes-relative-dimension-in-definition-of-smoothness I noticed the same problem.

Comment: @JürgenBöhm Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself got an answer to this question.

First, note that the condition 2. is stable under the base change along the morphism between schemes of finite type over $k$. You need to prove this in order to get over Proposition 10.1(b).

Take an arbitrary $z\in Z$. Let $X_z$, and $Y_z$ be the fiber of $z$ in $X$, and $Y$. Take an arbitrary irreducible component $X'$ of $X_z$. We must show that the dimension of $X'$ is $m + n$.

The generic point of $X'$ goes into an irreducible component $Y'$ of $Y_z$, when $f(X')\subseteq Y'\Leftrightarrow X'\subseteq f^{-1}(Y')$. Then, $X'$ is an irreducible component of $f^{-1}(Y')$ also. Because of [1], $f^{-1}(Y') \to Y'$ can be viewed a base change of $f$, with $Y'$ endowed with the reduced closed subscheme structure, and $f^{-1}(Y')$ with some corresponding scheme structure. Since condition 2. is stable under base change in a nice situation, $f^{-1}(Y') \to Y'$ also satisfies condition 2., and so $\dim X' = \dim Y' + m = n + m$. You know the last equality through the condition 2. for $g$, and Corollary 9.6 of Hartshorne.

[1][Image of base change of immersion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1802351/image-of-base-change-of-immersion/3053580#3053580)